# WordPress filter to modify final html output

Tags: wordpress

WordPress has great filter support for getting at all sorts of specific bits of content and modifying it before output. Like `the_content` filter, which lets you access the markup for a post before it's output to the screen.

I'm trying to find a catch-all filter that gives me one last crack at modifying the final markup in its entirety before output.

I've browsed the list of filters a number of times, but nothing jumps out at me:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

Anyone know of one?

Comment: here is the smartest solution I've spotted https://stackoverflow.com/a/48572083/2250843

Answer (score 22, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no hook for this, since the themes uses HTML which won't be processed by WordPress.

You could, however, [use output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start) to catch the final HTML:

```
<?php
// example from php.net
function callback($buffer) {
  // replace all the apples with oranges
  return (str_replace("apples", "oranges", $buffer));
}
ob_start("callback");
?>
<html><body>
<p>It's like comparing apples to oranges.</p>
</body></html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
/* output:
   <html><body>
   <p>It's like comparing oranges to oranges.</p>
   </body></html>
*/
```

Comment: You can use php register_shutdown_function to end buffering, and retrieve html.

Comment: This has a one drawback, you cannot call `ob_start, ob_clean, ..` inside the callback, which is needed for particular caching logic. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php#refsect1-function.ob-start-parameters

Answer (score 90):

WordPress doesn't have a "final output" filter, but you can hack together one. The below example resides within a ["Must Use"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) plugin I've created for a project.

Note: I haven't tested with any plugins that might make use of the "shutdown" action.

The plugin works by iterating through all the open buffer levels, closing them and capturing their output. It then fires off the "final_output" filter, echoing the filtered content.

Sadly, WordPress performs almost the exact same process (closing the open buffers), but doesn't actually capture the buffer for filtering (just flushes it), so additional "shutdown" actions won't have access to it. Because of this, the below action is prioritized above WordPress's.

wp-content/mu-plugins/buffer.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Output Buffering
 *
 * Buffers the entire WP process, capturing the final output for manipulation.
 */

ob_start();

add_action('shutdown', function() {
    $final = '';

    // We'll need to get the number of ob levels we're in, so that we can iterate over each, collecting
    // that buffer's output into the final output.
    $levels = ob_get_level();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++) {
        $final .= ob_get_clean();
    }

    // Apply any filters to the final output
    echo apply_filters('final_output', $final);
}, 0);
```

An example of hooking into the final_output filter:

```
<?php

add_filter('final_output', function($output) {
    return str_replace('foo', 'bar', $output);
});
```

**Edit:**

This code uses anonymous functions, which are only supported in PHP 5.3 or newer. If you're running a website using PHP 5.2 or older, you're doing yourself a disservice. PHP 5.2 was released in 2006, and even though Wordpress (*edit: in WP version < 5.2*) STILL supports it, you should not use it.

Comment: Note: I've only tested this in version 3.8.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Awesome, definitely by far most elegant!

Comment: I suggest to change the very last parameter of [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) from 0 to something bigger like 999 (from the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action): _Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution (...)_) to be sure to be the very last function to manipulate the output.

Comment: @Robert, if you do this, then WP's default action will run for the shutdown action, which will flush all of the ob levels. The default action does not capture the output, just flushes it, so the `final_output` filter will capture nothing. I believe, at least.

Comment: @Robert, sorry, were you talking about `add_action('shutdown')` or `add_action('final_output')`? If the latter, then yes, increasing it would not be a bad idea.

Comment: I'm talking about `add_action('shutdown')`. But you're right: something bigger than 0 won't be executed anymore.

Comment: Why `count(ob_get_level())` ? actually ob_get_level() returns the level (int). Try `while(ob_get_level()) $final .= ob_get_clean();`

Comment: Thanks @Wiliam, nice catch. I removed the `count()`, as that was a mistake, since `ob_get_level()` returns the actual count. Moving to a while block is unnecessary, and will incur additional calls to `ob_get_level()` with no added benefit

Comment: Note: Works with 4.2.4

Comment: Since posting, I've used this on many more project, and with all version of WP since 3.8. I haven't run into any problems.

Comment: Note that slight modification of this code can very effectively help you to get rid of "extra space" bug, it is when some php outputs have an extra trailing space; sometimes this bug can lead to very odd errors, especially in cases when it occurs in AJAX requests. Just append to $final only in case the text piece has no trailing space, that's it. This is literally the only solution of a trailing space bug in case when infected piece of codes are in DB.

Comment: Worked like a charm - 4.9.8

Comment: Works fine but broke cache (Comet Cache)

Comment: This broke functionality of login in my site.

Comment: Breaks "wp super cache", pages are not cached. Apart from that, it's a nice idea that needs some refinements and can come in handy for certain development pourposes.

Comment: Haven't tested this in the wild yet, but on my local environment I had it up and running in a second! Awesome!

Comment: When I tried this solution, my page was returned out of order. I needed to use $final = ob_get_clean() . $final;  in order to get things to come out in the correct order.

Comment: If you're going to run code like this, at the very least make sure it only runs on the front end

Answer (score 29):

The question is may be old, but I have found a better way to do it:

```
function callback($buffer) {
  // modify buffer here, and then return the updated code
  return $buffer;
}

function buffer_start() { ob_start("callback"); }

function buffer_end() { ob_end_flush(); }

add_action('wp_head', 'buffer_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'buffer_end');
```

**Explanation**
This plugin code registers two actions – `buffer_start` and `buffer_end`.

`buffer_start` is executed at the end of the header section of the html. The parameter, the `callback` function, is called at the end of the output buffering. This occurs at the footer of the page, when the second registered action, `buffer_end`, executes.

The `callback` function is where you add your code to change the value of the output (the `$buffer` variable). Then you simply return the modified code and the page will be displayed.

**Notes**
Be sure to use unique function names for `buffer_start`, `buffer_end`, and `callback`, so they do not conflict with other functions you may have in plugins.

Comment: You can prefix or suffix your examples: `buffer_start_so_772510` or `so_772510_callback` (I prefer to suffix, as it's easier to read). This way, when the code surfaces somewhere else, we know where it came from ;)

Comment: this doesn't work when the things that you want to modify or remove exists after the footer element

Comment: I recommend using kwoodfriend's solution, because it's way much safer (for example you can be sure to be the very last one to manipulate the output).

Comment: [http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/wordpress-hook-for-entire-page-using-output-buffering/](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/wordpress-hook-for-entire-page-using-output-buffering/) - this is the link, that this answer got copied from.

Comment: Is there a way to include headers in the code, so that the code can replace headers too?

Answer (score 18):

@jacer, if you use the following hooks, the header.php also gets included.

```
function callback($buffer) {      
    $buffer = str_replace('replacing','width',$buffer);
    return $buffer; 
}

function buffer_start() { ob_start("callback"); } 
function buffer_end() { ob_end_flush(); }

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'buffer_start');
add_action('shutdown', 'buffer_end');
```

Comment: Try not to make a post that references another answer (and requires reading the other answer to get the context); the more separated your answer gets from the answer you're referencing, the harder it is to understand what you're saying. Also, it's not necessarily bad to post an answer that builds off of the others, as long as you give credit where credit is due.

Comment: [http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/wordpress-hook-for-entire-page-using-output-buffering/](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/wordpress-hook-for-entire-page-using-output-buffering/) - this is the link, that this answer got copied from.

Comment: This solution does not work well. buffer_start is called twice and buffer_end never. I checked it with debug_log. Better stick to Kos' answer

Answer (score 8):

I was using the top solution of this post (by kfriend) for a while. It uses an `mu-plugin` to buffer the whole output.

But this solution breaks the caching of `wp-super-cache` and no supercache-files are generated when i upload the `mu-plugin`.

So: If you are using `wp-super-cache`, you can use the filter of this plugin like this:

```
add_filter('wp_cache_ob_callback_filter', function($buffer) {
    $buffer = str_replace('foo', 'bar', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to use wp super cache filter like this but its not working.. Also wp-rocket have similar filter called `rocket_buffer` and that is also not working. when i use filter name rocket_buffer,  my plugin works fine, wp-rocket can minify html and css but cached html files are not generated inside /cache directory (same for wp super cache. no file get generated). Any suggestion please? I would really appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 7):

Modified https://stackoverflow.com/users/419673/kfriend answer.

All code will be on functions.php. You can do whatever you want with the html on the "final_output" filter.

On your theme's 'functions.php'

```
//we use 'init' action to use ob_start()
add_action( 'init', 'process_post' );

function process_post() {
     ob_start();
}


add_action('shutdown', function() {
    $final = '';

    // We'll need to get the number of ob levels we're in, so that we can iterate over each, collecting
    // that buffer's output into the final output.
    $levels = ob_get_level();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++) {
        $final .= ob_get_clean();
    }

    // Apply any filters to the final output
    echo apply_filters('final_output', $final);
}, 0);

add_filter('final_output', function($output) {
    //this is where changes should be made
    return str_replace('foo', 'bar', $output); 
});
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a sentence for the less experienced saying what your snipped does exactly?

Answer (score 6):

To simplify previous answers, just use this in `functions.php`:

```php
ob_start();
add_action('shutdown', function () {
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    // ... modify $html here
    echo $html;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

You might try looking in the wp-includes/formatting.php file. For example, the wpautop function.
If you are looking for doing something with the entire page, look at the Super Cache plugin. That writes the final web page to a file for caching. Seeing how that plug-in works may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed there was a discusussion recently on the WP-Hackers mailing list about the topic of full page modification and it seems the consensus was that output buffering with ob_start() etc was the only real solution. There was also some discussion about the upsides and downsides of it: http://groups.google.com/group/wp-hackers/browse_thread/thread/e1a6f4b29169209a#

To summarize: It works and is the best solution when necessary (like in the WP-Supercache plugin) but slows down overall speeds because your content isn't allowed to be sent to the browser as its ready, but instead has to wait for the full document to be rendered (for ob_end() ) before it can be processed by you and sent to the browser.

Answer (score 4):

I've been testing the answers here now for a while, and since the cache breaking thing is still an issue, I came up with a slightly different solution. In my tests no page cache broke. This solution has been implemented into my WordPress plugin OMGF (which has 50k+ users right now) and no issues with page cache breaking has been reported.

First, we start an output buffer on template redirect:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'maybe_buffer_output', 3);
```

```
function maybe_buffer_output()
{
    /**
     * You can run all sorts of checks here, (e.g. if (is_admin()) if you don't want the buffer to start in certain situations.
     */

    ob_start('return_buffer');
}
```

Then, we apply our own filter to the HTML.

```
function return_buffer($html)
{
    if (!$html) {
        return $html;
    }

    return apply_filters('buffer_output', $html);
}
```

And then we can hook into the output by adding a filter:

```
add_filter('buffer_output', 'parse_output');
```

```
function parse_output($html)
{
    // Do what you want. Just don't forget to return the $html.

    return $html;
}
```

Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into problems with this code, as I end up with what seems to be the original source for the page so that some plugins has no effect on the page. I am trying to solve this now - I haven't found much info regarding best practises for collecting the output from WordPress.

Update and solution:

The code from KFRIEND didnt work for me as this captures unprocessed source from WordPress, not the same output that ends up in the browser in fact. My solution is probably not elegant using a globals variable to buffer up the contents - but at least I know get the same collected HTML as is delivered to the browser. Could be that different setups of plugins creates problems but thanks to code example by Jacer Omri above I ended up with this.

This code is in my case located typically in functions.php in theme folder.

```
$GLOBALS['oldschool_buffer_variable'] = '';
function sc_callback($data){
    $GLOBALS['final_html'] .= $data;
    return $data;
}
function sc_buffer_start(){
    ob_start('sc_callback');
}
function sc_buffer_end(){
    // Nothing makes a difference in my setup here, ob_get_flush() ob_end_clean() or whatever
    // function I try - nothing happens they all result in empty string. Strange since the
    // different functions supposedly have very different behaviours. Im guessing there are 
    // buffering all over the place from different plugins and such - which makes it so 
    // unpredictable. But that's why we can do it old school :D
    ob_end_flush();

    // Your final HTML is here, Yeeha!
    $output = $GLOBALS['oldschool_buffer_variable'];
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'sc_buffer_start');
add_action('shutdown', 'sc_buffer_end');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the output, you can use `template_include`:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', static function ( $template ) {
    if ( basename( $template ) === 'foo-template.php' ) {
      echo str_replace( 'foo', 'bar', file_get_contents( $template ) );
    }

    return null;
} );
```

If instead you want to override the output completely, you can use the action `template_redirect`.

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', static function () {
    wp_head();
    echo 'My output.';
    wp_footer();
    exit;
} );
```