# Remove type='text/javascript' from contact form 7 tags

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I removed most of the type attributes from my wordpress site but still I can see this on the contact form 7 tags, how do I remove them?

I was searching this on google but didn't find the solution. Please help!

**Note:** I am validating html on validator.w3.org it gives warning, please see below.

```
Warning: The type attribute is unnecessary for JavaScript resources.
```

Comment: Why would you need to remove the type attributes?

Comment: I am getting warning on Validator.w3.org

Comment: Please note these are just warnings, your code will be valid (in case you don't have any other errors). The validator is used for educational purpose but is far from a global base of doing stuff :) 
You might find what you want here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287830/remove-type-attribute-from-script-and-style-tags-added-by-wordpress Seems more WP sites suffer from this 'issue'.

Comment: It's a warning. "unnecessary" is not "forbidden". Why worry about it?

Comment: I do hope they will not ban the use of the type attribute because our apps rely on that to know what to do with the codeblock when it was fetched togheter with a partial view file...

Comment: @Brainfeeder — It just says "unnecessary for JavaScript". Very specifically "for JavaScript".

Comment: @Quentin my client is asking to remove them. As I know they are just warning not errors but still it would be helpful if this can be removed.

Comment: @Quentin Yes indeed it does... I never got that warning though...

Comment: @YasirKhan Ah yes clients... tell them it will *at least* be 2 months of work and send the bill :)

Comment: @Brainfeeder lol

Comment: I can fix it editing core files of the plugin but I want it to be done using function.

Comment: @YasirKhan I'm not a WP expert, any chance you have an option of catching the output before it renders? A simple `str_replace()` might do wonders?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22818089/1397220 
It is a plugin to catch all content before rendering and allows you to change it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mentioned that *your client* wants these tags removed. I assume you've explained to him that they're benign (and arguably sometimes *helpful*). Barring that, if you still need to remove these tags, you can just use a "run time replace" instead of trying to find *every. single. instance.* of a script that has that attribute, especially if one plugin or another doesn't enqueue scripts properly.

Take this function for instance:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    ob_start( function( $buffer ){
        $buffer = str_replace( array( 'type="text/javascript"', "type='text/javascript'" ), '', $buffer );

        return $buffer;
    });
});
```

The `template_redirect` hook effectively has access to all of the markup for the page. So you can instead just add it to an [Output Buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), run a simple [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on it, and return that output.

You'll notive I've added both quote notation types since either could be in your source code at some point. You could use a regex for it if you wanted, but the array of both notations should suffice.

Comment: Works like a charm, you've explained it well also.

Comment: My pleasure! Just a note: My initial thought was similar to @Riad Citaku's answer below - however there are many plugins that add scripts improperly and thus could be missed by filtering the `script_loader_tag`. It seems your client is adamant to have the tag removed so this solution is kind of the "use a hammer  to kill a fly" kind of solution

Answer (score 2):

This is how you remove `type="text/javascript"` from all JavaScript files with the WordPress filter `script_loader_tag`.

```
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'your_slug_remove_type_attr', 10, 2);
function your_slug_remove_type_attr($tag, $handle) {
    return preg_replace("/type=['\"]text\/(javascript)['\"]/", '', $tag);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't remove type="text/javascript" that was added by a plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
//w3c error wordpress
//we use 'init' action to use ob_start()
add_action( 'init', 'process_post' );

function process_post() {
     ob_start();
}


add_action('shutdown', function() {
    $final = '';

    // We'll need to get the number of ob levels we're in, so that we can iterate over each, collecting
    // that buffer's output into the final output.
    $levels = ob_get_level();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++) {
        $final .= ob_get_clean();
    }

    // Apply any filters to the final output
    echo apply_filters('final_output', $final);}, 0);add_filter('final_output', function($output) {
    //this is where changes should be made    $find=array('type="rocketlazyloadscript"',"type='rocketlazyloadscript'",'type="text/javascript"',"type='text/javascript'",'type="application/javascript"',"type='application/javascript'",'type="text/css"',"type='text/css'" );
    return str_replace($find, '', $output);});
function theme_name_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'script', 'style' ) );}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_name_setup' );
```

[Source code](http://www.findinall.com/blogs/wordpress-w3c-error-filter-to-modify-final-html-output/)

Answer (score -1):

I added CSS to the function and it solved my JS and CSS W3C validation warnings. Please let me know if you see errors.

```
//Remove JS and CSS types
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
ob_start( function( $buffer ){
    $buffer = str_replace( array( 'type="text/javascript"', "type='text/javascript'", 'type="text/css"', "type='text/css'" ), '', $buffer );

    return $buffer;
});
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question