# .htaccess remove double https:// http:// in the link

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, hyperlink, url-rewriting

I'm working on one of a client site, some weird reason, a lot of their link show like this: https://http://yourdomain.com/xxxx

It's fine to click the link when I use the console to see the source and will redirect to https://yourdomain.com but when it's front page(without console open), **click the button(link), will open https//yourdomain.com, will be missing ":" or "//"**

I tried to find where those content come from, but no luck, I can't not use DB to remove that old "HTTP", because everytime they create new resource will still have https://http://

**So I wonder can I use a .htaccess file to detect all those "https://http://" links to direct "https://" only.**

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is practical in .htaccess.  However, as a temporary solution until you solve the cause of the problem, you should be able to add code to replace bad links at the point WordPress finally "outputs" the page.

I was going to pen a solution but found I only had to modify code for "final output" already [here on stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772510/wordpress-filter-to-modify-final-html-output)  (itself based on [this article](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/wordpress-hook-for-entire-page-using-output-buffering/) )

Try adding the following to your theme's functions.php, or for permanence to your own custom site specific plugin.

```
function my_linkfix_callback($buffer) {      
    $buffer = str_replace( 'https://http://' , 'https://' ,$buffer);
    return $buffer; 
}

function my_linkfix_buffer_start() { ob_start("my_linkfix_callback"); } 
function my_linkfix_buffer_end() { ob_end_flush(); }

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_linkfix_buffer_start');
add_action('shutdown', 'my_linkfix_buffer_end');
```

Obviously this is just a temporary solution until you solve the cause of the problem

Comment: Thank you so much @scytale, I will try to see if that works.

Comment: Note when viewed from an "HTTPS" url BOTH `//http://` AND `https://http://` will generate `https://http://` links in a browser. So view the HTML source in your browser and if your ahref links are "//http://" you will need to modify the str_replace in above code.